# find distance using a light line

Tags: geometry, distance

Let's suppose we have a particular light frequency emitter and relative sensor array, and that there is no external source of this light.

This emitter has a know angle respect the receiver, and emit a point of line. Because the angle is known, we can determine the distance just by looking at which point in the sensor we read the point. This is the triangulation method, used by [image: laser range finder], [click here for an explanation](http://www.posterus.sk/?p=11526)

Now, I want to understand if it possible to use a line instead of a point, and a sensor matrix instead of an array, so we can get 2D reading.
This should work until the "wall" has a obliquity on the axis perpendicular to the light line, but then I can't find a way to "fix" this problem. I may use different pattern instead of a line, like point but then the problem rise if one or more of the point are out of range for the receiver. any thoughts?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking.Could you include a diagram to make your question clearer? Incidentally laser range finders use time of flight for single point measurements. You can only use triangulation if you measure from several different points, and this sounds a bit like what you're proposing in your second paragraph.

Comment: edited adding an article that explain the triangulation using the array sensor. This is the first method, anc can read the distance of a point. i want to add a dimension, so the light point became a line and the array sensor became a matrix, but algoritm get more complex, maybe impossible.

Comment: Now also in the [wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20140219133448/http://www.posterus.sk/?p=11526).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit muddy, but I believe the answer to everything is "yes, but..."  Here's what's described in the referenced article:  The laser produces a small spot on the target and the lens in the camera creates an image of that spot on one (ideally) pixel.  By using simple lens equations, or by similar triangles, if you know the lens focal length and the pixel dimensions (and which pixel is on the camera's (0,0) optic axis location), you can determine the distance to the target.

Since we never made an explicit definition of which axis in the plane perpendicular to the laser beam we just made this measurement, clearly we could make this measurement in "x" or "y".  However,  the only dimension in which we're determining a value is along the laser beam, i.e. perpendicular to the target.   That's the only thing you can measure.  If your question is whether you could move the laser+camera in "x" and "y" and measure the distance at various locations on the target, most certainly you could.

Comment: no, i want to read distance on all the X OR Y axes without have to move the laser+camera, so if i add  the laser+camera rotation, i get a 3d deph map (lidar).
So i have to read all the line in "one shot", and i can't undertand if it is possible.

Comment: ?? you wrote 'without hav[ing] to move' and then 'add rotation'. Which is it?  If you allow rotation, then aside from calibrating the origin of your system, you just have to account for the rotation angle when calculating the perpendicular distance to any (x,y) location.

Comment: ok, you can add 2 axes of rotation, but then the system will be really slow as every point is a new reading. If i can read a line, i will need only one rotation and the sistem will be a lot faster.

Comment: Then it's all a matter of timing. You can't read a line because you can't distinguish one source point from another. If you can pulse your laser in sync w/ sensor readout (while rotating one or both), you'll get data faster.

Comment: but what if i change the line in something else? maybe a crossboard?